# add image to uimageview dynamically from an array of images

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, load

I'm able to add a label and text field dynamically but the image doesn't display unless I used the actually name of the image.

This works 
    UIImage *individualTopImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];

I need to use the for loop and display all the images in the array.

```
 //lets create  views
NSInteger numberTopOfViews = topImages.count;
for (int i = 0; i < numberTopOfViews; i++) {

    //set the origin of the sub view
    CGFloat myOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    //create the sub view and allocate memory
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    //set the background to white color
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //create a label and add to the sub view
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 200.0f, 25.0f);
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is page number %d", i];
    myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    myLabel.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [myView addSubview:myLabel];

    //create a text field and add to the sub view
    myFrame.origin.y += myFrame.size.height + 10.0f;
    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    myTextField.placeholder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter data in field %i", i];
    myTextField.tag = i+1;
    [myView addSubview:myTextField];

    //create a uiimage and add to sub view
    myFrame.origin.y +=myFrame.size.height +50.f;
    //UIImage *individualTopImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];
    UIImage *individualTopImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[topImages objectAtIndex:i]]];
    UIImageView *topImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: individualTopImage];

    [topImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myFrame.size.width,myFrame.size.height )];
    [myView addSubview:topImageView];


    //set the scroll view delegate to self so that we can listen for changes
    self.myScrollView.delegate = self;
    //add the subview to the scroll view
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:myView];
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you log individualTopImage? Does that give you valid image objects?

Comment: yes, i get valid image objects. this seems to be the only line that doesn't work correctly  UIImage *individualTopImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[topImages objectAtIndex:i]]];

Comment: I don't understand your comment -- you say you get valid image objects, but then say that the line that creates these objects doesn't work.

Comment: the images are in the topImages array correct but for some reason in the individualTopImage object remains nil when I loop through the topImages array and attempt an set individualTopImage to the selected image.

Comment: What do you have in topImages? Images, or image names?

Comment: i have 5 UIImages in topImages

Comment: If you have actual image objects in your array, then you should just have UIImage *individualTopImage = topImages[i];